# Matplotlib: Why is it 'suptitle' not 'subtitle'?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I know it's a stupid question but I was wondering why does the name for sub-title called 'suptitle' in matplotlib?
Is it an abbreviation?

Comment: I would assume since it’s above it it’s super, not sub

Comment: Yes, its above all sub plots ! So Super

Comment: If it was a subtitle, it would need to be located below the other content of the figure, right? Just like submarines don't fly.

Comment: Here's the commit from long ago that added this function. https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/commit/0728c5532a0c76c4c0be4449933f74a6ccc843ab